# Observations about the "Search" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I am starting to have some doubts about the `search` tag.

The description says:

> Questions about search algorithm mechanics and implementation. *NOT* for questions about using search tools within an API (e.g. Google, Bing, Facebook).

Which is perfectly fine to me. However looking at the tag info:

> Searching is one of the most common and important tasks in Computer Science.
>
> The most basic search algorithm is a linear-search (also called "sequential search"). Each item in a collection of data is examined in sequence until the sought item is found.
>
> If the collection in question has already been sorted then a more efficient binary-search is possible.
>
> Search can become more complex when, rather than finding one instance of a specific item, we want to find all items meeting a certain set of criteria. For instance a sql query can specify extremely complex search criteria, and much of relational database design involves the planning of an efficient way to perform those searches.

This already starts being confusing to me since I would not merge `SQL` search related questions with `tree` or `graph` search questions, or more in general with search-algorithm related questions (as `binary-search` or `linear-search`).

Anyway just visiting [the list of question tagged as search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/search) you can have a rough idea of how heterogeneous are the questions there (SQL, Wiki Api, search for algos, search in search engines, ecc.)

I would like to understand whether this is correct and a wanted "behaviour" or if you think it may be improved. Imho the tag is, at the moment, too dispersive and I doubt it helps to categorize a set of questions where one can have an expertise to help.

Comment: I think your intuition is right.  That tag is too broad to be particularly useful.  It needs to be split up into some more focused topics.  But that would be a very large task.

Comment: I think that it should at least put on hold until it is not decided what to do with it. Until that day, we'll keep seeing mixed (and mistagged) questions.

Comment: There is no way to put a tag on hold.  We could change the wiki message, but that has a long history of being ineffective if the tag is already popular.